# Use batch file to remove special characters from csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file, special-characters

I have a csv file with 18 fields. I have written a batch file to manipulate the data. Everything works except removing the comma from the "DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC" publisher. That field does not parse correctly. I have tried looking at other batch files for examples, but I am not familiar with the snytax.

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
( FOR /f "tokens=1-18 delims=," %%A in ('More +4 datatest.csv') do (
rem H is the department code
rem S is the sales tax code
rem Q is the publisher code
    Set "H=%%H"
    Set "S=T"
    Set "Q=%%Q"
    if "%%Q"=="BOOM! STUDIOS" Set "Q=BOOM STUDIOS"
    if "%%Q"=="DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC" Set "Q=DEVILS DUE"
    if "%%H"=="1" Set "H=1005" 
    if "%%H"=="1" Set "S=N"
    if "%%H"=="2" Set "H=1009" 
    if "%%H"=="2" Set "S=N"
    if "%%H"=="3" Set "H=1008"
    if "%%H"=="4" Set "H=1002"
    if "%%H"=="5" Set "H=1006"
    if "%%H"=="6" Set "H=1003"
    if "%%H"=="7" Set "H=1011"
    if "%%H"=="8" Set "H=1011"
    if "%%H"=="9" Set "H=1004"
    if "%%H"=="10" Set "H=1016"
    if "%%H"=="11" Set "H=1015"
    if "%%H"=="12" Set "H=1015"
    if "%%H"=="13" Set "H=1011"
    if "%%H"=="14" Set "H=1009" 
    if "%%H"=="14" Set "S=N"
    if "%%H"=="15" Set "H=1013"  
    if "%%H"=="16" Set "H=1017"
    echo "",%%~M,%%~N,%%~L,"","","","","",!H!,"","",ITEM,"","",%%~D,%%Q,"","",%%E,"",%%E,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",%%A,"","","","","",!S!,N,"","",DIAMOND,%%B,"",""
  )
)>paygoinvoice.csv
@echo on
```

Comment: I suggest you use `fnr.exe` to find and replace the characters. What actual problem do you have with the script you posted?

Comment: I am attempting to insert the following -- if "%%Q"=="DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC" Set "Q=DEVILS DUE" -- but I think the comma in the publisher name is causing issues...

Comment: You still haven't explained an issue. Does it not remove what you want?

Comment: I have edited the question -- everything works except removing the comma from the "DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC" data

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid From reading his question you can see he is not trying to remove data but simply change it. Because he is using `delims=,` the `for` satment does not see it as it was removed by `delims=` & the line was treated as an `%%x` variable.

Comment: I hope you can see by this point that batch can be a little cumbersome for this task so I suggest again that you use a cmd line program like fnr.exe or something like powershell. Here's some powershell that I beleive does what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403217/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-file-using-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that the `delims=,` you have in your `FOR` loop is causing to change `DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC` or **ANY** comma's in your code as a space.

Combine this with `Tokens=` then `%%H` **=** `DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS` ---And--- `%%I` **=** `LLC`.

A quick and dirty fix *(That I know of)* is to simply change all `", "` to something different before running it into the main function. For my example I used `1Comma1`. This will change your `IF` search to `DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS1Comma1 LLC`.

**Fixed.Bat:**

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem | Replace all ", " with "1Comma1"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ('"type datatest.csv"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET modified=!string:, =1Comma1 !

    >> datatest.csv.TEMP echo(!modified!
    endlocal
)

Rem | Main .CSV Edit Function
( FOR /f "tokens=1-8* delims=," %%A in ('More +4 datatest.csv.TEMP') do (
    Set "ItemData=%%H"
    if "%%H"=="1" Set "ItemData=1005"
    if "%%H"=="3" Set "ItemData=1008"
    if "%%H"=="BOOM STUDIOS" Set "ItemData=NEW STUDIOS"
    if "%%H"=="DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS1Comma1 LLC" Set "ItemData=DEVILS DUE"

    echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,!ItemData!,%%I
  )
)>paygoinvoice.txt
del datatest.csv.TEMP

@echo on
```

**PS:** The code I used for your example above was taken from your last post about the subject. Simply add your new code where it belongs.

Also keep in mind that `EnableDelayedExpansion` auto removes `!` from the output of an `FOR` loop or `IF` statement.

Comment: I am following most of what you wrote. The SET modified command alters the string by replacing the comma with 1Comma1 correct? I know the last line creates a new file called datatest.csv.TEMP but I don't understand how the last line outputs the file. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @SteveRichter Correct, the `SET` command uses syntax-replacement to change each comma to `1Comma1`. The basis of how it works is by outputting each line by line to `datatest.csv.TEMP` via `>>`. Pretty simple way of text altering without the need of larger scripts or powershell.

Comment: — could I replace the comma with “” and avoid having to remand the data element in the Tweak Script section?

Comment: @SteveRichter What you mean like change `1Comma1` to `""`...? By having `delims=,` it will still quay that comma.

Comment: Sorry, that should say “rename” the data element

Comment: @SteveRichter There I made an EDIT to it, that should be a little more main stream.

Comment: — No, I mean leave the delims as-is (paragraph marker) and use “” instead of 1comma1. That way, the comma gets removed from the token (publisher data), which is my goal.

Comment: @SteveRichter I see what you mean, if you want, just simply add another replace function to turn the remaining `1Comma1` Back to the proper `,`. You can even make it a `call "%1" "%2"` type function.

Answer (score 0):

As you never showed a real world sample input file, it is difficult to help.

The problem with `for /f` parsing csv files is :

1. that it does **NOT** obey double quoted fields and will also tokenize included commas,
2. treats adjacent delimiters as only one, and ignores leading ones.

So the 1st issue applies, the 2nd is unknwon.

One work around is to **not** parse the field(s) in question and pass them quoted as arguments to a sub which **does** obey the quotes, and process them there.

To ease handling of array values there exits a technique to expand lists to an array, see it implemented in the following batch for `DepCode` and `STaxCode` (as I hinted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916868/6811411) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916055/replace-string-in-csv-file-using-batch-file)):

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Build array DepCode[1..16]
Set i=0&Set "DepCode=,1005,1009,1008,1002,1006,1003,1011,1011,1004,1016,1015,1015,1011,1009,1013,1017"
Set "DepCode=%DepCode:,="&Set /a i+=1&Set "DepCode[!i!]=%"
:: Set DepCode

:: Build array STaxCode[1..16]
Set i=0&Set "STaxCode=,N,N,S,S,S,S,S,S,S,S,S,S,S,N,S,S"
Set "STaxCode=%STaxCode:,="&Set /a i+=1&Set "STaxCode[!i!]=%"
:: Set STaxCode

( FOR /f "tokens=1-16* delims=," %%A in ('More +4 SO_53917950.csv') do (
    rem H is the department code
    Set "H=!DepCode[%%~H]!"
    rem S is the sales tax code
    Set "S=!STaxCode[%%~H]!"
    rem Q is the publisher code 17th field and 18th field 
    Call :RemoveComma %%Q 

rem echo "",%%~M,%%~N,%%~L,"","","","","",!H!,"","",ITEM,"","",%%~D,"!PubCode!","","",%%E,"",%%E,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",%%A,"","","","","",!S!,N,"","",DIAMOND,%%B,"",""
    echo "%%~A","%%~B","%%~C","%%~D","%%~E","%%~F","%%~G","!H!","%%~I","%%~J","%%~K","%%~L","%%~M","%%~N","%%~O","%%~P","!PubCode!","!R!","!S!"

  )
)>paygoinvoice.csv
Goto :Eof

:RemoveComma
Set "R=%~2"
:: remove comma from field
::Set "PubCode=%PubCode:,= %"

:: split field at first comma or slash/backslash
for /f "delims=,/\" %%a in (%1) do Set "PubCode=%%a"
```

This constructed input file SO_.csv:

```
first  line to remove
second line to remove
third  line to remove
fourth line to remove
"HeadA","HeadB","HeadC","HeadD","HeadE","HeadF","HeadG","HeadH","HeadI","HeadJ","HeadK","HeadL","HeadM","HeadN","HeadO","HeadP","HeadQ","HeadR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","2","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","3","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","4","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","5","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","6","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","7","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","8","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","9","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE /1FIRST COMICS, LLC","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","10","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM! STUDIOS","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","11","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM! STUDIOS","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","12","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM! STUDIOS","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","13","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM! STUDIOS","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","14","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM! STUDIOS","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","15","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM! STUDIOS","ColR"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","16","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM! STUDIOS","ColR"
```

Will have this output (with remarkably slower processing due to the additional call):

```
"HeadA","HeadB","HeadC","HeadD","HeadE","HeadF","HeadG","","HeadI","HeadJ","HeadK","HeadL","HeadM","HeadN","HeadO","HeadP","HeadQ","HeadR",""
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1005","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","N"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1009","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","N"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1008","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1002","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1006","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1003","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1011","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1011","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1004","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","DEVILS DUE ","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1016","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM STUDIOS","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1015","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM STUDIOS","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1015","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM STUDIOS","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1011","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM STUDIOS","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1009","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM STUDIOS","ColR","N"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1013","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM STUDIOS","ColR","S"
"ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD","ColE","ColF","ColG","1017","ColI","ColJ","ColK","ColL","ColM","ColN","ColO","ColP","BOOM STUDIOS","ColR","S"
```