# Using variable as index in batch-array fails

Tags: arrays, batch-file, indexing

I want to iterate though a batch-array:

```
SET DEF_APP[0].type=.html
SET DEF_APP[0].name=Firefox
SET DEF_APP[1].type=.htm
SET DEF_APP[1].name=Firefox
SET DEF_APP[2].type=.doc
SET DEF_APP[2].name=LibreOffice
SET DEF_APP[3].type=.docx
SET DEF_APP[3].name=LibreOffice

SET I=0
:APP_LOOP 
IF DEFINED DEF_APP[%I%].type ( 
   ECHO %DEF_APP[%I%].type% %I%
   ECHO %DEF_APP[%I%].name% %I%
   SET /A I=I+1
   GOTO :APP_LOOP 
)
ECHO "Length is" %I%
ECHO %DEF_APP[1].type% %I%
ECHO %DEF_APP[1].name% %I%

PAUSE
EXIT
```

While %I% is printed out as 1,2,3,4 it seems, that %I% can't be used as the index of the array. Printout is:

```
I 0
I 0
I 1
I 1
I 2
I 2
I 3
I 3
"Length is" 4
.htm 4
Firefox 4
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

I wonder, why the printout from the array is always "I" (no error or something)?
In other examples (like in [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_arrays.htm) in the example below) it should work. They are using a "CALL ECHO %%..."

```
set Arr[0] = 1 
set Arr[1] = 2 
set Arr[2] = 3 
set Arr[3] = 4 
set "x = 0" 
:SymLoop 

if defined Arr[%x%] ( 
   call echo %%Arr[%x%]%% 
   set /a "x+=1"
   GOTO :SymLoop 
)
echo "The length of the array is" %x%
```

When I print out

```
ECHO %DEF_APP[1].name% %I%
```

(like the last two echoes), it prints out the correct value  "Firefox 1".
When I print do

```
SET I=1
ECHO %DEF_APP[%1%].name% %I%
```

it prints out "I 1". Can it be, that the index %I% is overgiven as char instead of int? And why is the letter "I" printed?

Comment: `%DEF_APP[%I%].type%` are two variables with a string in between: first variable `%DEF_APP[%` (empty), string `I`, second variable `%].type%` (also empty). Read about [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/59680701#59680701

Comment: You are not the first, who fell into the famous "delayed expansion trap" (and you won't be the last). :-) Thanks for your help, your example is perfectly explained, Stafan.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understand the expansion or why it fails, is the order of the three different expansion phases.

First the percent expansion occurs.
All variables between percent signs are expanded here.
It doesn't guess variable names. It simply take the chars between percent signs.
These phase expands variables BEFORE analyzing is executed, this is important especially for code blocks.

Then For variables (they uses also percent signs) are expanded.
And the last expansion is the delayed expansion (must be enabled)

If the line is prefixed with a CALL command, then a fourth expansion round starts. It's a percent expansion.

To your array problem:

```
SET I=1
ECHO %DEF_APP[%I%].name% %I%
```

Can't work, as the percent expansion tries to expand `DEF_APP[` and `].name`

You could use

```
Echo !DEF_APP[%I%].name! %I%
```

Now the %I% expands and then the DEF_APP[1].name

Answer (score 1):

Let me share my way of doing this, and, I am not the author of that method.
This is the safe way to define/use arrays in cmd/bat.

I saw this on [dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6429) /by [@Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) and after [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917950/use-batch-file-to-remove-special-characters-from-csv-file) /by @user6811411 (removed user), some time ago.
The original layout code is some like:

**`Set "var=%var:,="&Set /a i+=1&Set "var[!i!]=%`**

I prefer replace **[]** to one **_**

Also, change **i+=** to **_i+=1+0**, no need predefined command: **`set i=0`**

But it always works, and requires **`enabledelayedexpansion`** variables

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && title <nul && title ...\%~nx0

rem :: define a variable for array_layout ::
set "_def_app.type=.html,.htm,.doc,.docx"
set "_def_app_.name=firefox,libreoffice,libreoffice"

rem :: replace/incrementing delimiter by a set /a_i+1%% :: 
rem :: (miracle loop in set new variable _var_+i/index) ::
set "_def_app.type_0=%_def_app.type:,="&set/a _i+=1+0&set "_def_app.type_!_i!=%"
set "_def_app_.name_0=%_def_app_.name:,="&set/a _k+=1+0&set "_def_app_.name_!_k!=%"

rem :: use a for loop to echo/use the index array value i/I ::
echo/ && for /l %%i in (0 1 !_i!)do for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('echo/!_def_app.type_%%i!
')do echo/  %%I == ^^!_def_app.type_%%%i^^!

rem :: use a for loop to echo/use the indesx array value k/K ::
echo/ && for /l %%k in (0 1 !_k!)do for /f tokens^=* %%K in ('echo/!_def_app_.name_%%k!
')do echo/  %%K == ^^!_def_app_.name_%%%k^^!

rem :: get total index + 1 = positions
echo/ && for %%s in (i,k)do call set /a "_len_%%s=!_%%s!+1"

echo/  Index of [^^!_def_app.type^^!] is: 0-!_i!
echo/ Length of [^^!_def_app.type^^!] is: !_len_i!

echo/ && echo/  Index of [^^!_def_app_.name^^!] is: 0-!_k!
echo/ Length of [^^!_def_app_.name^^!] is: !_len_k!

%%_APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- Outputs:

  ---

```bat
  .html  == !_def_app.type_0!
  .htm  == !_def_app.type_1!
  .doc  == !_def_app.type_2!
  .docx  == !_def_app.type_3!

  firefox  == !_def_app_.name_0!
  libreoffice  == !_def_app_.name_1!
  libreoffice  == !_def_app_.name_2!

  Index of [!_def_app.type!] is: 0-3
 Length of [!_def_app.type!] is: 4

  Index of [!_def_app_.name!] is: 0-2
 Length of [!_def_app_.name!] is: 3

Press any key to continue...
```

---

- Same code without comments...

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && title <nul && title ...\%~nx0

set "_def_app.type=.html,.htm,.doc,.docx"
set "_def_app_.name=firefox,libreoffice,libreoffice"

set "_def_app.type_0=%_def_app.type:,="&set/a _i+=1+0&set "_def_app.type_!_i!=%"
set "_def_app_.name_0=%_def_app_.name:,="&set/a _k+=1+0&set "_def_app_.name_!_k!=%"

echo/ && for /l %%i in (0 1 !_i!)do for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('
echo/!_def_app.type_%%i!')do echo/  %%I == ^^!_def_app.type_%%%i^^!

echo/ && for /l %%k in (0 1 !_k!)do for /f tokens^=* %%K in ('
echo/!_def_app_.name_%%k!')do echo/  %%K == ^^!_def_app_.name_%%%k^^!

echo/ && for %%s in (i,k)do call set /a "_len_%%s=!_%%s!+1"

echo/  Index of [^^!_def_app.type^^!] is: 0-!_i!
echo/ Length of [^^!_def_app.type^^!] is: !_len_i!

echo/ && echo/  Index of [^^!_def_app_.name^^!] is: 0-!_k!
echo/ Length of [^^!_def_app_.name^^!] is: !_len_k!

timeout -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your comment. This intents to showing how to set/use/print variable in array, and how to handle index, positions value. Understand, my English have no support here/now to help-me to explain more, have you some suggest?

Comment: @DavidPostill, it might not be the solution, but it shows me my error (like the comments above). For me it was very helpful.